# How to use certutil -exportPFX to export certificates from "Certifiate Enrollment Requests" store?

Tags: certutil

I have Windows Server 2008. I am trying to write a script to export my certificate request private keys. I wanted to use the powershell cmdlet `Export-PfxCertificate` to export my certificate request's private keys, but it seems that cmdlet is missing from Server 2008. So I tried the certutil command, but I keep getting the error:

```
CertUtil: -exportPFX command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I know the particular serial number and thumbprint, but it seems like I am not specifying the `[CertificateStoreName]` correctly.  In powershell, the location is `cert:\LocalMachine\REQUEST`,  but I cannot get the format for certutil.

I have tried many versions of

```
certutil -f -enterprise -exportpfx 05..hexdigits...0a C:\private.pfx
```

But no success. `certutil -store -?` was not in figuring out the correct format.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Certificate Signing Requests are stored in a separate store (named REQUEST) from normal certificates.  Use this:

```
certutil -exportPFX -user -p "password" REQUEST $SerialNumber "a.pfx"
```